# How to make Firefox search only part of selected link text?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Instead of making Firefox search the whole sentence of the link, how do I make searching part of highlighted text?

[image: Screenshot 1]

Is there any `about:config` properties can be change to make it more like Google Chrome as below?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? Firefox behaves the same as chrome for me using Firefox 5.0 (From 2011!)

Comment: I am using Mozilla Firefox 30.0 on Windows 8.1 64-bit. This issue do not occur on non-linked text. Only linked text have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following link: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2850797 which shows someone with the same problem.

They discovered that it was a bug introduced to firefox recently, which has a bugzilla entry at: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=985824

According to a post on that thread:

```
This issue is verified fixed on Firefox 31 Beta 1
```

So I imagine you will have to update firefox when possible, or download a beta for now.

Comment: I can confirm the bug was fixed in version 31.